# PhpStorm - Deployment - Cannot Upload New Files

Tags: ftp, phpstorm, sftp

When I try to create a new file/folder in PhpStorm I get a `Permission denied` error. However, when I create a new file in a folder that already exists in the root directory of my server I can without any errors.

When I try to create a new file:

```
[2016-03-07 11:29 AM] Failed to transfer file 'C:\Users\D\PhpstormProjects\example2\test.php': could not write to "sftp://www.example.com/test.php". (Permission denied)
[2016-03-07 11:29 AM] Automatic upload completed in less than a minute: 2 items failed
```

When I try to create a new folder:

```
[2016-03-07 11:27 AM] Failed to create folder '/var/www/html/test': could not create folder "sftp://www.example.com/test". (Permission denied)
[2016-03-07 11:27 AM] Automatic upload completed in less than a minute: 1 item failed
```

Comment: information of technical environment please (OS, guest, host, web server, etc...) ?

Answer (score 5):

You can try this :

```
chmod -R 777 /var/www
chgrp www-data /var/www
chown -R www-data /var/www

useradd -G {www-data} your_username
```

Comment: I get `chgrp: invalid groupd: 'www-data'`

Comment: While this code snippet may be the solution, [including an explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-%E2%80%8C%E2%80%8Bcode-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Comment: You should never tell some one to use permissions 777.

Answer (score 4):

The issue solved itself after restart.

PhpStorm support gave this answer:
Please try to run File > Invalidate Caches/Restart > Invalidate and Restart.

If it still fails please send me idea.lof file as described here:
 https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/207241085-Locating-IDE-log-files

Comment: Clearing caches seems to have solved the issue. My flavor of the error message had `(Indicated packet length 1416128883 too large)` added to it. Server-side permissions were correct, `ssh server` worked fine, but PHPStorm still wasn't able to connect until I flushed its caches.

Comment: Just another +1 for File > Invalidate Cache and restart, worked for me.

Comment: Worked for me as well. My error was `Failed to transfer file C:\path_to_file: Could not resolve file sftp:0.0.0.0/var/www/html/test.php (Permission denied)`.

Answer (score 4):

Prior to deleting, modifying and transferring files, you need **to give them the permissions to the data group for the user** who will perform the operations.

```
$ sudo usermod -a -G www-data your_username
$ sudo chgrp -R www-data /var/www/html 
$ sudo chmod -R g+w /var/www/html
```

Answer (score 3):

Checklist:

- **Make sure you own the files**, so if you are in the `sudo` group then you can do `sudo chown -R myusername:sudo /var/www/html/test/`. This is to make sure that it will also work for other people in the group.
- **Make sure that you have write permissions**, i.e. read and write access also for the group. You can do this with `sudo chmod -R 755 /var/ww/html/test/` (Unfortunately I have found that in practice you sometimes need 777 permissions, but this is not desirable.)
- **Make sure your deployment path mappings are correct**, by going to Settings | Deployment | Mappings, and check that the Deployment path is indeed relative to the root path (under Connection)

Answer (score -2):

After fixing permissions on server you need restart phpstorm. Worked for me on Ubuntu 17.10